# install vosk api (speech to text ) in Windows 10 environment by c#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I read the document  https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api  but the prerequisites for installation  vosk api are in the Linux environment and python  as follows

```
cd csharp && KALDI_ROOT=<KALDI_ROOT> make
wget https://alphacephei.com/kaldi/models/vosk-model-small-en-us-0.4.zip
unzip vosk-model-small-en-us-0.4.zip
mv vosk-model-small-en-us-0.4 model
mono test.exe
```

If I want to run the prerequisites of  vosk  api in Windows 10 environment and in C # programming language, I do not know how it is, I mean how can I run C # example https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/blob/master/csharp/test.cs  in Windows  10 environment.

Comment: They just don't support windows yet:  https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/issues/246

Comment: Make sure your python is 3.8 and 64bit. Mine is 3.7 so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is not what you are looking for but I just tried to install it on ubuntu 18.04 LTS and hopefully it may help others

```
1. Make sure python is 3.x
2. Make sure pip3 is pip-20.x.x: 
    -check version: pip3 -V (if it returns: pip 9.0.1)
    -upgrade it like so: pip3 install --upgrade pip
    (now pip version shall read pip-20.3.3 or newer)
3. Now it ready to install vosk: pip3 install vosk 
(with no problem)
```

Windows installation needs python 3.8 and 64 it:

```
Python installation from Pypi
The easiest way to install vosk api is with pip. You do not have to compile anything.

We currently support the following platforms:

Linux on x86_64
Raspbian on Raspberry Pi
Linux on arm64
OSX
Windows
Make sure you have up-to-date pip and python3 versions, see detailed requirement below:

Python version: 3.5-3.8 (Linux), 3.6-3.7 (ARM), 3.8-3.9 (OSX), 3.8-64bit (Windows)
pip version: 19.0 and newer.
```